# How can I get the value of the selected radio button on another jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp

I have written a JSP program in Java for an online quiz. An admin can put a question and it will store that in the database. And a student is able to see all the questions from the database.
Now the problem is that - 
for each question there are 4 options and I'm not able to read the value from the radio button on the next JSP program. Here is the code

quiz.jsp

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/LUV'S/Documents/NetBeansProjects/quiz/question.
        s = con.createStatement();
        int i=1;
        ResultSet rs= s.executeQuery("select id,question,option1,option2,option3,option4 from question where category=2");
        while(rs.next()){
        String id = rs.getString("id");
        String question = rs.getString("question");
        String option1 = rs.getString("option1");
        String option2 = rs.getString("option2");
        String option3 = rs.getString("option3");
        String option4 = rs.getString("option4");
        out.println("<div class='container'>");
        out.println("<table class='table table-bordered'>");
        out.println("<thead>");
        out.println("<tr class='danger'>");
              out.println("<th>"+i+") "+question+"</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</thead>");
        out.println("<tbody>");
        out.println("<tr class='info'>");
                 out.println("<th><input type='radio' value='1' name="+id+"> "+option1+"</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("<tr class='info'>");
                 out.println("<th><input type='radio' value='2' name="+id+"> "+option2+"</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("<tr class='info'>");
                 out.println("<th><input type='radio' value='3' name="+id+"> "+option3+"</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("<tr class='info'>");
                   out.println("<th><input type='radio' value='4' name="+id+"> "+option4+"</th>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        out.println("</tbody>");
        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</div>");
        i++;
       }
```

and examser.java

```
con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/LUV'S/Documents/NetBeansProjects/quiz/question.accdb", "", "");
    Statement s5 = con1.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1 = s5.executeQuery("select id,answer from question where category=2");
    while (rs1.next()) {
        String answer = rs1.getString("answer");
        String id = request.getParameter("id");
        out.println(id);
    }
```

Right now in my DB I'm having two questions in category 2. When I click on Submit it moves to examser and in the screen "null null" is printed. It means that the value from the radio button is not read. Can you tell where I went wrong?

Comment: In quiz.jsp you set the radio button's name to an id which you had retrieved from a SQL query. So I guess this ID is not "id". But in examser.java you're looking for parameter with name "id". The names don't match.

Comment: For such a situation it is always helpfull to print all request parameters for debugging purposes.

Comment: as @vanje says, you should be doing something like `request.getParameter("7");` or whatever possible ID value retrived form database, although i suggest using some name format includes the ID, because som duplication may occure, and mess the whole thing, example `name=rad_opt_"+id+"`

Comment: Inorder to get Name match what should i do? @vanje

Comment: The question is, why do you want the radio button's name dynamic in the first place? If you show only one question per page, then a static name would be enough. Either way you must ensure to know the right names in your servlet.

Comment: Can you @vanje help me out for showing one question on page with code. I cannot figure out how to implement?